# C array treated differently on Windows & Ubuntu

Tags: c, arrays, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I wrote some C code for a college project, which ran without issues on Ubuntu, where I write all my code. When It was marked the teacher said that it produced no output. It still works for me however, but my suspicion that the teacher ran my code on Windows proved correct, when I found my code broke when run on Windows. I hunted the problem down. It was the following:

I have the char array:

```
char grade[2];
```

It then has the contents of another char array(`char grade_str[3]`), which contains, for instance, "B3", copied into it(I am aware this is a mistake)

```
strcpy(grade, grade_str);
```

The string `grade`(supposedly now equal to "B3") is compared to a file full of grades in order to get a match(using `strcmp`). Except that on Windows(7 to be exact), it never matches, because `grade` It ends up looking something like this, "B30~$)", with several extra random characters tacked on. Since the array is only 2 bytes, this shouldn't be. I know the problem is almost certainly due to me not providing enough space for both the string AND a null byte, and using `char grade[3];` does indeed fix the situation. 
However, I would like to know why I get no errors when compiling on either Windows or Ubuntu, and why further, it runs perfectly every time on Ubuntu, but never on Windows. I feel like I'm going to have to check my code on Windows AND Linux from now on... or is there a way to make sure these errors are raised properly by the compiler, some sort of super vigilant mode??

**Compilers used:**

- Ubuntu: gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2)
- Windows 7: Just updated it, so pretty sure it's mingw32 gcc 4.7

Comment: It's impossible to catch all memory access errors at the compile time in languages like C.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I would have thought it was possible... I will now delete this question, so if someone else has the same question, they will have to ask all over again.

Comment: There is no initialisation shown. `char grade[2];` is just a declaration or tentative definition. A `char [2]` is an array of 2 `char`s, but you try to move 3 `chars` into it!

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: Because you are using char arrays as your strings, there is no end string character `'\0'`, and so strcopy doesn't know where the string ends. My guess is that in Ubuntu, when it allocates the memory for the char array, adds the null string terminator after the array, or you just got lucky

Comment: @mikeyq6 I thought it might be something like that too..

Comment: @mikeyq6 *Because you are using char arrays as your strings, there is no end string character '\0', and so strcopy doesn't know where the string ends.*  `strcpy()` **NEVER** "knows" where the string ends - no matter what arguments you pass it.  Even `strncpy()` doesn't "know" where the string ends - you have to provide a value to tell it what's safe to use.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True. I just meant that if you were using string literals, eg. `"B3"`, then the string terminator is added for you

Comment: This (specifically, accessing array `grade` with invalid index in `strcpy`) is *undefined behavior*, which means, anything can happen, including things appearing to work correctly, your program crashing, or your program starting to install malware on your computer.

Comment: @Olaf thanks, I knew that was the problem... just not why I was getting no errors, and why it continued to work on Ubuntu.. but I'm getting the picture now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand that it actually doesn't work correctly on Linux... What happens is that it keeps reading in the memory until it finds a null character.

So maybe in Linux you got lucky and the byte next to your array was a zero, and on Windows you were not lucky.

But it's anyway bad programming, you should always have a null terminated string, else this can result in bugs that are very hard to find...

To give you an example of it not working, Ubuntu gives you some room in the memory to store variables. So you have one or two variables like your array. One day you will add another variable, and Linux will store it rigth after your array. Then it might work at the beggining of your program, then you will initialize your new variable, then when you access your array it will crash...

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that it's bad.. but it consistenly works in Ubuntu, no matter how I change the input, which I find interesting. Windows is having none of it

Comment: It doesn't matter much why a wrong program works in some circumstances, it's still wrong.

Comment: @Totem maybe it will "work" 1000 times but the 1001th time it will fail. Or maybe it will fail everytime, once you have updated your compiler to the latest version. It's _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: "_So maybe in Linux you got lucky_" -- I would consider it to be _unlucky_ if it worked.

Comment: @CoolGuy Exactly right

Answer (score 2):

Calling string functions on strings that are not NULL-terminated is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) ("UB"). UB means that it's not known what will happen. It might work, or it might not work. In your case, it works on Linux, it doesn't work on Windows. Once you have UB, you cannot predict what will happen.

UB is always something to look out for and be aware of in C. The language does not prevent you from doing something that results in UB. You need to be careful on your own. Compilers like Clang and GCC can help you detect it, but there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

You can use clang's address sanitizer to catch such errors in runtime.

Let assume you have buggy code:

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char grade[2];
    char grade_str[] = "B0";

    strcpy(grade, grade_str);

    return 0;
}
```

You can compile it with `-fsanitize=address`:

```
clang -fsanitize=address main.c
```

If you run your program, it will break with some debug info.

```
==19588==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd9bcf7422 at pc 0x455bc0 bp 0x7ffd9bcf7350 sp 0x7ffd9bcf6b08
WRITE of size 3 at 0x7ffd9bcf7422 thread T0
==19588==WARNING: Trying to symbolize code, but external symbolizer is not initialized!
    #0 0x455bbf (/tmp/a.out+0x455bbf)
    #1 0x47afd1 (/tmp/a.out+0x47afd1)
    #2 0x7fa15d228ec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)
    #3 0x47ac3c (/tmp/a.out+0x47ac3c)
[... and so on]
```

You will find more information in [clang's documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)

Comment: `return strcpy(grade, grade_str) - grade;` And you get a conversion problem `conversion to ‘int’ from ‘long int’ may alter its value`

Comment: @Michi I have removed subtraction. It wasn't necessary to reproduce OP error.